# Trying to get specific QCheckBox state from many created dynamically

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I have this code in which I create a number of QCheckBoxes through a loop:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        self.dbutton = QPushButton("Press ME")
        self.dbutton.setEnabled(False)
        self.button_state = 0

        self.checkbox_layout = QFormLayout()
        for i in range(5):
            self.checkbox = QCheckBox()
            self.checkbox.toggled.connect(self.enable_button)
            self.series_info = QLabel(str(i))
            self.checkbox_layout.addRow(self.checkbox, self.series_info)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.dbutton)
        layout.addLayout(self.checkbox_layout)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def enable_button(self):
        print(self.checkbox.isChecked())
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the state of the specific QCheckBox that is triggering the signal to the `enable_button` slot, but I'm getting this weird behavior, where The state is show as `False` until all buttons are enable, but then it immediately flips to `False` as soon as just one of them is unmarked, as shown in the gif below. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: 1. don't create instance attributes in a for loop, as it's completely pointless, since they'll be overwritten at every iteration and you'll always get the last created one; 2. use partials or lambdas: `checkbox.toggled.connect(lambda _, chk=chk: self.enable_button(chk))` and get the button by adding the argument to `def enable_button(self, chk):`; 3. similarly, use [`self.sender()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) to get the object that emitted the signal, without the function argument; 4. add the button to an instance attribute list, and use `lambda _, i=i` to get its index as argument.

Comment: Note that point 1 is the main issue in your code, because it makes no sense to create instance attributes with the same name reference in a for loop (unless you **really** know what you're doing). Creating `self.checkbox` in the for loop is completely pointless because it's just like doing `self.checkbox = QCheckBox()` over multiple lines: whenever you try to get `self.checkbox` *after* the for loop, it will always get the *last* created object to which that `self.checkbox` references to; simplifying: `x = 0; x = 1; x = 2; print(x)` will obviously print 2.